# Where to put documentType in the ER diagram?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Currently I am going to build a really simple database for a online shopping system which includes 5 tables.

1. Client
   id
   firstname
   lastname
   phone
2. Product
   id
   name
   price
   stock
3. Document
   id
   url
   size
4. Client_Document
   client_id
   document_id
   timestamp
5. Product_Document
   product_id
   document_id
   timestamp

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiLAJ.jpg)

Table 4 and table 5 are link tables, which is used to define client related documents and product related documents.

Now I need to add the type of the document. Such as "brochure", "product_photo" , "id_document" and "avatar". I am wondering where should I add it? In the Document table or in those two link tables?

Comment: If you drew your ERD it would be so much easier.

Comment: I have just uploaded the ER diagram.

Comment: For sure the Documents table, based off that ERD.

Comment: But how can I restrict the type for each document? For example, a client document cannot have the type as "brochure" and a product document cannot have the type as "avatar". If the type is in the link table, I can easily restrict the type value, but how can I do that if the type is in the document table?